# Seting up folder from Apache root directory in other hdd and allow php to write on it

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, httpd.conf, virtual-directory

please need help...
[LINUX]

I'm trying to set up a big photos folder in a new hdd over apache.

Before it was: /htdocs/photos  now I'm trying to create a virtual directory:
`<IfModule alias_module>`
`Alias /photos "/home/photos"`
`<Directory "/home/photos">`
`<IfModule alias_module>`
`Alias /photos "/home/photos"`
`<Directory "/home/photos">`
 ...and it works accesing it from outside
 but PHP when I upload a new photo it creates on the OLD /htdocs/photos not in /home/photos
What should I do? A symbolic link?? a bit insecure isn't it? I don't know
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A symlink from /home/photos to your htdocs/photos should be finde. Don't forget to add:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

to your vhost config.